# Selinux Error when starting xampp on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, linux-mint, selinux, writable

I'm running XFCE4.10 on ubuntu / mint 17.1.

Xampp start fine when i manually open manager-linux-x64.run from /opt/lampp/ but once i create a shortcut on the desktop (from Thunar 1.6.3), this new shortcut won't start xampp (nothing happens). When i try to launch that shortcut from a terminal, i get the following error :

> Unable to initialize installer. Is /tmp writable ? Is SELinux enabled?
>   You may need to disable it temporarily Please see below for details
>   http://fedora.redhat.com/docs/selinux-faq-fc3/index.html#id2826056

Comment: so, what are the answers to those questions? can you add them to your question?

Comment: Seems to be package by BitRock install builder. Running `INITDEBUG=1 ./manager-linux-x64.run` migt help.